How Can I Determine If a Device Is Paired Using CoreBluetooth (Swift)?
I am working with CoreBluetooth to connect to a BLE device. I want to verify if the device is already paired before performing certain actions. I followed the steps mentioned in this StackOverflow post, but I am facing an issue. Even though my device gets paired successfully, the didWriteValueFor delegate method is not being called.
Here is what I have done so far:

Scanning and Connecting:
I scan for peripherals and connect to them successfully.
Discovering Services and Characteristics:
I discover the services and characteristics of the connected peripheral.
Writing to a Characteristic:
I attempt to write to a characteristic after ensuring that the device is paired.

Despite these steps, the didWriteValueFor method is not invoked. I’m sure the device is paired correctly. How can I reliably determine if a device is paired, and what could be causing didWriteValueFor not to be called?
class BluetoothManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    private var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        connectedPeripheral = peripheral
        connectedPeripheral?.delegate = self
        centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        connectedPeripheral?.discoverServices()
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
        
        for service in services {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        let value = 1234
            let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: value) { Data($0) }
            for characteristic in service.characteristics!
            {
                if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                    peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withResponse)
                }
            }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error writing value: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Successfully wrote value to \(characteristic.uuid)")
        }
    }
}


What if the characteristic doesn't have notify capability? Then you won't attempt the write? Have you confirmed that the write is actually attempted?  Is this your actual code?  Normally you would check the service and characteristic identifiers to ensure you have the right ones. You mention pairing. Does your chracteristic need encryption? Is the system pairing dialog being triggered? Or do you just mean connected?

Thank you for your comment. I double-checked everything and discovered that the issue is likely caused by using two instances of BluetoothManager.

It's good that you solved your problem. You should post a self-answer outlining the cause and what you did to fix it. How did you wind up with 2 instances of BluetoothManager? (Also, make it clear that BluetoothManager is your class, not a system class.)

The main source of the problem was that the dependency injection container I used for the app created more than one BluetoothManager. When I changed the BluetoothManager Instance to singleton instance, the problem was solved.
